# How to add a <span> inside <h1> in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to do this in Wordpress `<h1>This is my <span>title</span></h1>` but how do I get a `<span>` into the funciton. `<?php the_title(); ?>`.

Searching the codex I found the `$after` parameter, so I tried:

```
<h1><?php the_title( $after ); ?><span class="my-class"> text</span></h1>
```

which works but I bet there is a nicer way  than hard coding it into the html. I'm just a designer putting together my first wordpress theme so be patient. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: you mean `<h1><span><?php the_title() ?></span></h1>`?

Comment: why do you need to, if it its just to add a class, why not apply it to the h1 ?

Comment: Agree with Dragon, make a special h1 class if you need to.

Comment: <h1>This is my <span>different color here</span></h1>

Answer (score 1):

Customizing WordPress themes is actually quite simple.  In this case you need to find the class used by the title. Let's assume it is the basic  tag like you mentioned.  You would them modify the stylesheet of your theme (you can use the WordPress editor) and add the following line to the bottom:

```
/* Custom CSS */

h1 {<custom css> !important;}

.red {color: #FF0000;}
```

This will override the CSS for all h1 throughout your theme so be careful.  It also keeps the original CSS in tact in case you ever need to revert.

You then can update your code like this:

```
<h1>some text goes here<span class="red">some red text goes here</span></h1>
```

Of course you can do this inline as well:

```
<h1>some text goes here<span style="color:#FF0000;">some red text goes here</span></h1>
```

Comment: <h1>This text is black <span>and this one is red</span></h1>, that what I want to do

Comment: this is not a .css issue, what your showing is the render of the browser but when you go the wordpress template page what you see is the function <?php the_title(); ?>

Comment: If you want to change only a portion of the_title() to red text you will have to hardcode it using ove of the methods above instead of calling it by the_title().

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering myself.

1. First go to the page you want add the subtitle and right at the top of your page click **Screen Options**[image]
2. Then check **Custom Fields**
   [image]
3. After that, at bottom of the page you will see this new field. Type: the **Name** of the field (an identifier) and the **Value** (the text you want to append to the h1). Then click **Add Custom Field**
   [image]
4. You will see something like this
   [image]
5. Then go to your page or template page and add this code

   `<?php 
   $sub_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle',true); 
   if($sub_title != '') { 
   echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'<span>' .' '. $sub_title .'</span></h1>'; 
   } else { 
   echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'</h1>'; 
   } 
   ?>`
6. This is the result
   [image]